# Remove icon in Dock from recent apps

Tags: macos, dock

I need to hide app icon in Dock after closing the app. By default Dock shows icons of recent apps.

I can't use LSUIElement because I need icon when the app is running.

Also NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory) doesn't fit my needs, because I need the main menu and icon when app is running.